# Is it okay to ask a question on past situation at workplace SE?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I am relatively a new member of this community but in my 10+ years of experience there were several situations at my workplace where I could have used some advice from this community. I still wonder about them if I handled it right or should I have done something else. 
So I just want to know is it okay to ask questions about situations which happened in past where the answer would only give a perspective but not affect my action/career now? (at least not directly). 
At the same time asking such questions may be construed as just a `waste of time` for people who are taking time to answer them as the situation actually does not exist today.

Comment: I mean, you could ask them, but unfortunately they wont help you anymore. Theoretically as long as they are on topic and well formulated that's all we care about it. You may have been better off just posting them as if it was the present though. Then, no one would know the difference and it wouldn't have mattered anyway.

Comment: @SaggingRufus. Thanks. I was thinking of doing that i.e. making the situation 'present' but I just was not sure if it is a good idea. Thanks for your thoughts though.

Comment: @SaggingRufus I wouldn't suggest pretending it's about a current situation. It complicates matters when we ask for feedback and there's no real reason to as it's fairly normal for past tense questions to come up and I haven't seen them get any less attention because of that.

Answer (score 12):

Yes. There are many questions like that here already.

If it's a question that could apply to others, it will still be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the input

Comment: Fully agree with Joe: as long as it's useful there's no problem with asking about past events. You do need to pay attention to how you phrase your core question though @PagMax. "*Did I make the right call?*" is even less useful than an open-ended "*What should I do?*". Those sorts of questions are very dependent on situation-specific details and hard to answer. "*What other options did I have?"* or "*How should I handle this in the future?*" are better and less likely to attract close votes.

Comment: Not only if they could apply to others - also if they could apply to yourself, in the future.